# Modifications to Neon Sign Transformer to turn it into a variable DC power supply?

Tags: power-supply, ac, transformer, dc

I would like to turn a neon sign transform into a DC power supply.

Looking into this it would appear I need some rectifiers to turn the AC output into DC. 
I could use a variable resistor to adjust voltage.
I am unsure how to adjust current. Is there such a thing as a variable adjusting circuit that bleeds off current to the neutral line?

Or is there an easier inexpensive way to make my own DC power supply capable of 4kV and 30mA?

Comment: Firstly finding diodes for rectifiers that are capable of over 4kV is a bit of a niche product area. Secondly if you limit the voltage, it will limit the current - apply 4kV to a 133k resistor and 30mA will flow through it, but half the voltage or increase the resistance and the current will drop (\$V=I\times R\$). Thirdly, 4kV @ 30mA is enough to kill you dead (I know the dead bit is redundant, but it is there for emphasis), and by dead I mean the kind of dead that you don't come back from. So be **VERY** careful.

Answer (score 2):

You need diodes to rectify the HV   AC  output to make DC and depending on your application the HV  DC should be filtered.A filter capacitor rated for the job is needed.You could get these parts by stripping out  dead microwave ovens of the older type that still uses 50Hz components .Its probably best to make a fullwave bridge rectifier with the diodes and use the caps for filtering .If you just cant find HV parts then you can place components in series to make the high voltage rating .Since this is only 50Hz then simple balancing resistors across each part will work satisfactory.I suggest that you use a Variac to give you the variable voltage .If you wont do a variac then at a pinch a light dimmer could work .Now if you dont know what you are doing then dont do this proposed PSU or any HV.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this video using an oil burner transformer with a homemade variable resister. If you look at the screen shot I took it is just an alligator clip and thick copper ground wire wound into a coil. As far as d/c current goes, I believe that would be done with how you use the spark gap. Someone else would have to answer that.

[image: coil]

[image: full curcuit]

---

I think this is the circuit being used in the video.
[image: circuit]

Here is the video link.
[MAKE AN ELECTRET](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7NR36yUDyPg)

---

One more thing. A flyback transformer that has built in HV diodes.

[image: Flyback transformer]

I found it here:
[20kV DC power supply](http://rimstar.org/science_electronics_projects/high_voltage_power_supply_w_flyback_transformer_builtin_diodes.htm)